# How is the group of reals generated by positive reals under addition?

Tags: group-theory

$\left ( \mathbb{R},+ \right )$ is generated by $\mathbb{R}_{> 0}$

Can someone explain please?

Thanks.

Comment: You say "non-negative" but writing $\Bbb R_{>0}$ suggests "positive". Which one do you mean? (i.e. do you include $0$ or not?)

Comment: @Wojowu yes it's positive. Sorry, corrected the question

Comment: Thank you everyone for all your answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the group generated by a set $A$ contains all the additive inverses of elements in $A$, whence negative numbers.

Comment: Ok but how can you write $-1$ as a result of addition of elements of $\mathbb{R}_{> 0}$?

Comment: @John11 You can't. But a subgroup generated by a subset $A$ is something more than just result of adding arbitrary elements of $A$.

Comment: @John11 You can't, but this is a matter of *definition* of the group generated by $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ - it's the smallest group that contains $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$, and thus must contain additive inverses.

Answer (score 1):

The subgroup generated by $S$ is by definition the smallest subgroup containing $S$. Any group that contains the positive reals must contain their inverses also or else it would fail to be a group.

Answer (score 1):

The group generated by a subset $A$ is the smallest group that contains this subset.

Explicitly, this the set of all elements that can be written as compositions of elements from $A$ and *their inverses.*

What you seem to be thinking about would be the semi-group generated by $A$ this is the set of all elements that can be written as compositions of elements from $A$.

(There is one more subtle point, namely that for the subgroup one includes the empty composition and thus one gets the neutral element always, while one does not for the subsemigroup, one would for the submonoid, though.)